# XDocument XML Parsing Issue

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm using XDocument and LINQ to parse some XML files, and some worked fine, but others did not.  Looking into it, I found the difference:

Files that work look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Scenarios xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Scenario>
        ...
    </Scenario>
</Scenarios>
```

Files that don't look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Scenarios xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Scenario>
        ...
    </Scenario>
</Scenarios>
```

If you don't see it, the missing element is the :xsi alias in the root element.

I just want to know why this is the case.  Files that are otherwise the same won't be parsed by XDocument.Load() unless they have that alias.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, “won't be parsed”? What exactly happens? Does it throw some exception? Do you have any elements that use the `xsi:` prefixed in the XML that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you are saying that any node (element or attribute) with the `xsi` prefix is from the XML schema namespace.

In the second example, you are saying that any node without any prefix is in the XML schema namespace.

You either need to make the declaration like the first if you have nodes with the `xsi` prefix or remove those nodes.

**EDIT**: As svick correctly noted, XDocument does not perform schema validation by default, so the issue is more likely that the `...` contains some nodes with an `xsi` prefix

Comment: You're mostly right, but I don't think `XDocument` actually validates the document according to the schema, unless you explicitly validate it yourself.

Comment: @svick I had not actually checked that it validated.  Answer updated to give a more likely reason.